# Use string format create a 2D list

Tags: python, string, formatting

Assume input 'table' is a   list    of  lists   of  strings,    the goal is create  and return  a   formatted
string  representing    the 2D  table.

- Each  row of  the 2D  table   is  on  a   separate    line;   the last    row is  followed    by  an  empty   line
- Each  column  is  aligned to  the left;
- Columns   are separated   with    a   single  vertical    bar '|';    and there   must    be  exactly one space
  before  and after   the vertical    bar;
- Every row starts  and ends    with    a   vertical    bar;    and there   must    be  exactly one space after the 
  leading bar and before  the ending  bar

Here is what I got:

```
def show_table(table):
    new_string = '' 
    for i in table: 
        for j in range(len(i)):
            line = i[j]
            new_string += '| {} '.format(i[j])
        new_string += '|\n'

    return new_string
```

My code works in some cases when rows' spacing is equal. For example:

```
input: [['A','BB'],['C','DD']]
output: '| A | BB |\n| C | DD |\n'
print:| A | BB |
      | C | DD |
```

However, when the rows are not similar like:

```
input: [['10','2','300'],['4000','50','60'],['7','800','90000']]
```

It causes my output to differ:

```
Right_output: '| 10   | 2   | 300   |\n| 4000 | 50  | 60    |\n| 7    | 800 | 90000 |\n'
my_output: '| 10 | 2 | 300 |\n| 4000 | 50 | 60 |\n| 7 | 800 | 90000 |\n'
```

And the right output should properly looks like:

```
| 10   | 2   | 300   |
| 4000 | 50  | 60    |
| 7    | 800 | 90000 |
```

my output:

```
| 10 | 2 | 300 |
| 4000 | 50 | 60 |
| 7 | 800 | 90000 |
```

Where do I need to modifier my code to make my print out match the right output? I guess it's something about the max width of columns?

Comment: AFAICS your output does meet the requirements while your desired output don't (there is more than one space before some vertical bars). Now if you still want the other output then yes, you need to compute the width of each column first, then use it when formatting each string. That means walking through the input twice, I don't think you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for [padding](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) a string with `str.format()` (aligning to the left) is like this:

```
>>> '{:10}'.format('test')
'test      '
```

You need to precalculate the widths of columns before printing the table. This produces the right output:

```
def show_table(table):
    new_string = ''

    widths = [max([len(col) for col in cols]) for cols in zip(*table)]

    for i in table:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            new_string += '| {:{}} '.format(i[j], widths[j])
        new_string += '|\n'

    return new_string
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code totally makes sense. The small error is new_string += '| {{:>{}}} '.format(widths[j]).format(i[j]). I think '>' makes the each column aligned to the right. I changed it to "<" and it makes my code pass all test cases.  Thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: @markzzzz: Right, `>` aligns to the right. To align to the left, you can just omit it (I've updated the post).

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired output, I integrated the maximum width of the table elements into your function:

```
def show_table(table):
    max_widths = map(max, map(lambda x: map(len, x), zip(*table)))
    new_string = '' 
    for i in table: 
        for j in range(len(i)):
            line = i[j]
            line = line + ' '*(max_widths[j]-len(line)) 
            new_string += '| {} '.format(line)
        new_string += '|\n'

    return new_string
```

To explain the max_widths line...

```
max_widths = map(max, map(lambda x: map(len, x), zip(*table)))
```

...it could be done in 3 steps:

1. Transpose rows and columns of the table

   ```
   transposed = zip(*table)
   ```
2. Get the lengths of all strings to allow comparison

   ```
   lengths = map(lambda x: map(len, x), transposed)
   ```
3. Get the maximum length per column

   ```
   max_widths = map(max, lengths)
   ```